# Tweak SwiperJS after load

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightbox, elementor, swiper.js

I have a website that was build with Wordpress & Elementor.

In this site there is a SwiperJS Carousel
(Elementor is using it as a carousel widget),
And when clicking on this swiper it opens a lightbox
With another Swiper (same content, just bigger).

My problem is: Elementor won't let you change the direction
of the lightbox's swiper. and i need to change it :)

**So my question is:**
Is there a way to change the swiper direction after it was loaded?

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean rtl/ltr?!

Comment: Yes, i mean RTL/LTR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is an example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-43-change-direction
use the `changeDirection` function